# Understanding Cross Browser Transform & Origin

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser, transform

I'm obviously missing something here and hoping someone can fill in the blanks for me about cross browser `transform` & `origin` in use with SVG.

So the quick version of the question, why does the example below look/work as expected in Chrome, but the `origin` is messed up in Firefox, and in IE the `transform` doesn't appear to work at all? (The red thing should circle around the green ellipse evenly as it does in Chrome but for all browsers).

Am I just not specifying properties correctly, missing a necessary prefix to transform in regards to IE? I've been doing Desktop dev for too long and am kicking the rust off some web skills so I appreciate any slice of humble pie you might provide. :)

> [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/LRGEOQ)

```css
@keyframes rotateIT {
  0% {} 100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateIT {
  0% {} 100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#damnit {
  animation: rotateIT 3s ease infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Yes, I left the objects off-center of canvas on purpose for this example of origin issues. -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="150px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" enable-background="new 0 0 150 150" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#00A651" cx="57.5" cy="55.5" r="25"/>
<g id="damnit">
 <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M63,23.475c13.742,2.354,24.567,13.357,26.639,27.192h10.078C97.516,31.312,82.265,15.87,63,13.368V23.475z
  "/>
 <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M25.361,50.667c2.105-14.059,13.247-25.2,27.306-27.306V13.283C33.088,15.51,17.51,31.088,15.283,50.667
  H25.361z"/>
 <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M52.667,87.639C38.832,85.567,27.829,74.742,25.475,61H15.368c2.502,19.265,17.944,34.516,37.299,36.717
  V87.639z"/>
 <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M89.525,61C87.21,74.52,76.52,85.21,63,87.525v10.106C82.042,95.159,97.159,80.042,99.632,61H89.525z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: bonus points for selector name

Comment: Read on the known issues http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: ....and people wonder why I'm such a big xaml fan lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DaniP points out, caniuse.com is going to be your go-to resource for figuring out cross-browser issues. From the more direct link http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d: IE <= 10 doesn't support transforms on svg elements.

And FF has trouble with `transform-origin` on svg elements. Search SO for ["firefox transform-origin svg"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox%20transform-origin%20svg) - there are some answers where people get it working (e.g. with `transform: rotate(deg, cx, cy)`) but those aren't working for me when I test your example. Mozilla has a couple bugs related to this - e.g. the closed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193, where the last comment is "this shouldn't be closed"

Comment: Given that Firefox implements the specification as written and Chrome does not it's rather inaccurate to say that Firefox has trouble.

Comment: @RobertLongson that's fair, and I didn't mean to insult your work. "You wouldn't be the first dev to be tripped up by the way FF handles `transform-origin` in svg elements"?

Comment: I'm going to leave this up for a bit longer before accepting in case someone comes along with a trick that doesn't require Greensock. Yet one more reason I wish SMIL support was more adopted...

Comment: Note that I've also removed the misleading last comment on bug 923193. That comment led to a bug that was closed as invalid. Given that Firefox implements the specification either Chrome needs to change or the specification needs to change (to match Chrome).

Comment: @RobertLongson you're welcome to edit the wording of my answer if you want - the points you're making are absolutely valid

Comment: Changing the meaning of someone else's answer is not really on. It's your answer, not mine. I'd write my own answer rather than edit yours if I thought it would help any.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as answer since I'd rather not answer my own question but I did get it figured out decently with `cx,cy` addition as origin - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/LRGEOQ). I didn't recall seeing any shorthand for rotate(deg,cx,cy) but gave it a go when I got a minute to test. Cheers.

Comment: Chris glad you got it working! // @RobertLongson it wouldn't be changing the meaning - I agree with what you're saying and I'm looking for your help with phrasing. But I guess this conversation covers it well enough, so I'll leave my wording as is